# How to add or substract minutes from a timediff result in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query that will show all worked hours, days and persons.
I have that runnning.

Asume i have a table called uren:

```
rec_id | user_id | start (datetime) | eind (datetime)
```

and i have table called users

```
user_id | name        |
```

With the query below i nearly have all the info i want.

```
select users.name, sec_to_time(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(uren.eind, uren.start)))),count(distinct(date(start))) as dagen
from uren, users
where date(uren.start) between CAST('2017-10-04 00:00:00' as Date) and CAST('2017-11-04 00:00:00' as DATE) and
      uren.user_id = users.user_id
group by uren.user_id
ORDER BY name
```

Which shows me this

```
Piet (name) 230 (hours total) 24(days worked)
```

Now comes the real question:

I want to subtract 30 minutes for each day worked less then 5 hours.

Im clueless atm.
Can someonme please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one row per user per day:

```
select users.name,
       (sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(uren.eind, uren.start))) -
                    30 * 60 * sum(time_to_sec(timediff(uren.eind, uren.start)) < 5*60*60)
                   )
       ),
       count(distinct(date(start))) as dagen
from uren join users
     on uren.user_id = users.user_id
where date(uren.start) between '2017-10-04' and '2017-11-04'   
group by uren.user_id
order by name;
```

If one day has multiple shifts, you need to aggregate by day first:

```
select u.name,
       (sec_to_time(sum(day_secs) -
                    30 * 60 * sum(day_secs < 5*60*60)
                   )
       ),
       count(*) as dagen
from (select uren.user_id, uren.name, date(uren.start),
             sum(time_to_sec(timediff(uren.eind, uren.start))) as day_secs
      from uren join
           users
           on uren.user_id = users.user_id
      where uren.start >= '2017-10-04' and uren.start < '2017-11-05'   
      group by uren.user_id, date(uren.start)
     ) u
group by name
order by name
```

Comment: 1 date can contain multiple shifts but ill have a go with what you showed me above Thanks alot!  wil let you know if it works

Comment: Tried your solutiuons again and it worked great:) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason that you do not have a clue.  It is because what you are asking is quite complex.

The first thing you need to accept (and I mean despairingly accept) is that your function depends days and users, and therefore, you need group by both, at first, then only by users in the final result.  To do this, you will need a subquery that groups by days and users, before the parent can group by users.

Here is what I came up with...

```
SELECT 
users.name,
sec_to_time(SUM(ur.timeWorked)) as tWorked,
SUM(ur.dagen) as Dagen

 FROM users
 INNER JOIN ( 

   SELECT
   user_id,

   SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`eind`, `start`))) - (1800 * 
     IF(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`eind`, `start`))) < 18000,1,0))
   as `timeWorked`,

  count(distinct(date(`start`))) as `dagen`

  FROM uren

  WHERE date(`start`) 
    BETWEEN CAST('2017-10-04 00:00:00' as Date) 
    AND CAST('2017-11-04 00:00:00' as DATE)
      GROUP BY user_id, DAYOFYEAR(`start`)

    ) as ur ON ur.user_id = users.user_id

GROUP BY ur.user_id
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: (btw i changed the 30 minutes into 900 seconds as i was wrong in my first asumption) At first glance it seemed to work perfectly, but ran into something strange. A worker had 3 shifts over 3 days and all shifts was less then 5 hours, total worked hours was 7 hours and 8 minutes. it should have removed 3x 15 minutes so the result would be 6:23  but im getting 6:38.

Comment: btw what does (SELECT @underFive:=0) as uf in the last part do? whats uf?

Comment: Using a variable has some problems.  You alluded to it in your last comment.  In the first row of the query the a variable has to be already set and this is done in the FROM part of the query.  This gets too complex when the variable has an IF condition.  I did away with it all together. This revised answer should work.